# Finding the Period of a Signal by Its DTFT Data

Tags: fourier-transform, homework

[image] find period of DTFTs where vertical lines represent Dirac deltas

Comment: are you in the same course as  praneeth bharath? His question contains a [screenshot](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50305/filters-and-their-properties) of seemingly the same workbook. $$ $$ our problem with both questions is the same: we really can't help you if you're not even showing what you've tried so far, and where you've got stuck. You *need to ask your own **specific** question*!

Comment: No I dont know who he is

Comment: I don't know on what basis I should consider them as 5-periodic signal or 15-periodic signnal